# Change Temperature Monitor to display in Fahrenheit

Tags: raspbian, temperature, cpu

Can I change the temperature monitor on LXPanel on Raspbian in the GUI to display in Fahrenheit? If so how do I change it?

Comment: *Presumably* you mean on raspbian, and *presumably* you are using LXDE there, and *presumably* this is a widget for monitoring core temp.  But who knows?  Other than you of course...

Comment: Why not convert it to Fahrenheit yourself? It's a mathematical simple conversion.

Comment: Just convert it to Fahrenheit..

Comment: the maths isnt the problem, I need figure out what I need to change so the display is in F and not C, if possible. and how to do it. I'm not a linux expert (yet) so step-by-step instructions would be great.

Comment: you are correct on all accounts @goldilocks. It was pretty late when I posted the question, and I thought I had all the details.

Comment: Sorry if that seemed harsh.  The upside of there being various such monitors around is that there are some that will output in Fahrenheit, e.g., `gkrellm`.

Comment: it's all good. It didn't even occur to me to ask for alternatives. thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 4):

If it's the LXDE "Temperature Monitor", it seems to be just reading `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`, which returns an integer value in millicelsius.

If it's not hard-coded, try setting the language/locale to where you are in `raspi-config`. Otherwise … welcome to how most of the world indicates temperature ☺

Comment: I set it to en_us.UTF-8 but no luck. I might just have to change to fit the rest of the world, lol :D

Comment: +1 Might also (or instead) be in `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/` depending on your kernel.